# N1QL: dynamic key or value as object key / alias

Tags: javascript, couchbase, sql++

Say in Bucket **User** I have documents like

```
{
  "email": "dave@gmail.com",
  "fname": "Dave"
}
```

and

```
{
  "email": "earl@gmail.com",
  "fname": "Earl"
}
```

Using **N1QL** can I get output as

```
{
  "Dave": "dave@gmail.com"
},
{
  "Earl": "earl@gmail.com"
}
```

That means can we replace alias of a key name with a value from the document. If yes please provide me the query format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Couchbase 4.5, you can do:

```
SELECT OBJECT u.fname : u.email FOR u IN [ `User` ] END
FROM `User`;
```

Comment: Thanks @geraldss.
Tried at http://query.pub.couchbase.com, **OBJECT** is not being identified as Keyword, also giving fatal error. Can you provide any link regarding this information?

Comment: The online tutorial has not yet been upgraded to the latest version, which includes the OBJECT keyword. You may need to install locally.